# How to force wrapper div to keep its optimal width according to its children

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem here in Chrome (maybe in other browsers too). 
I have a wrapper div which floats to the left. It contains some child div and these divs float to the left too and they have different widths according to their contents. I defined a max-width property for the wrapper div and as you can see in the fiddle code when the wrapper reaches this max-width, the last child in the wrapper moves to the next line but the wrapper keeps the maximum width and there are a lot of empty space on the right.
I'd assume the wrapper's size should be recalculated and should have a smaller width because it floats.

I'd like it, because in my real code the wrapper has "sexy" css but it looks rude with empty spaces.

Sorry for my English, I hope you'll understand my problem. Has anyone an idea how I can resolve this problem without any JS (or just a little bit of JS)?

Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/Xd9PV/1/

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="float float-1">apple</div>
        <div class="float float-2">banana</div>
        <div class="float float-3">orange</div>
        <div class="float float-4">some very delicious strawberries</div>
    </div>​

    .wrapper {
        border: 1px solid red;
        float: left;
        max-width: 300px;
    }

    .float {
        border: 1px solid blue;
        float: left;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a clear:both to the last div element like this:

```
.float {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.float:last-child {

    clear:both;
}
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not possible using CSS. When you set a max-width, it won’t recalculate it’s width after x floats have dropped to other lines because of the overflow.

You can use javascript/jQuery to calculate this for you instead that inserts a break where needed, f.ex:

```
var width = 0,
    maxWidth = 300, w;
$('.wrapper .float').each(function() {
    width += ( w = $(this).outerWidth() );
    if ( width > maxWidth ) {
        $(this).before('<div style="clear:left"></div>');
        width = w;
    }
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2mfbY/

Comment: Good thinking, include a 100kb library.

Comment: @AlexFl ever heard of gzip?

Comment: "It’s not possible using CSS": That's not true. Look at Alih Nehpets's answer. It resolves my problem.

Comment: @ruff that doesn’t solve it, it just adds a break before the last element regardless of measures. Try adding another float and see what happens: http://jsfiddle.net/WtPNy/

Comment: @David, I'm understand you, that's right. But Alih's solution is still good enough for me.

Comment: @ruff OK then, all good. But your problem was not the max-width, it was that you wanted to put the last element on another row using CSS, and you tried using max-width to solve it. So the question was not very clear.

Comment: @David Sorry for it. I'm not a good questioner because of my poor English but I'm working on it. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `ellipsis` (But I am not sure whether it seems OK to you or not)

```
.float  {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: left; padding:0 2px;
    margin-right: 5px; max-width:90px; 
    text-overflow:ellipsis ; 
    white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden
}
​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Xd9PV/5/)**